# Button setonclicklistener error

Tags: android, events, button, onclick

I am having a problem right now with `setOnClickListener`.

When i put this following line:

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And run the application then it does not run and shows a message that "Application closed forcefully".

Could you please help me how I can set button onclick event in Android 2.2?

Comment: Please share the code and error log :)

Answer (score 7):

See if the code below works for you...

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {              
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }    
});
```

Remember to add `});` at the end.

Comment: thank you very much for the answers. I got the solution. Actually i was putting the code of the button onclicklistener in Splash screen coding page.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For defining button click event in android,
You can try the below code:

```
public class Main_Activity extends Activity {


    private Button myButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new Button_Clicker());
}

class Button_Clicker implements Button.OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       if(v==myButton)
       {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Hello!! button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }    
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

another possible reason ( happened to me ) is your activity must implement `OnClickListener`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Although it's been a long time, thought it might help others who have this problem, it took me many trials to get it right. But i think what finally solved my problem was setting the clickable attribute of a button in the layout's xml to true.
Code sample:

```
<Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true">
</Button>
```

Further, if you would've looked at the DDMS perspective, you would've seen that the cause of the error was NullPointerException, which ofcourse was showing because clickable wasn't set. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I would like to correct myself. I dont think the above is the correct solution. If anyone is getting a NullPointerException, even though button has been correctly assigned using findViewById, i.e `Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.somebutton);` , then i would suggest, to clean current build and rebuild. It happened to me a few times.

Answer (score 2):

Type `View.onClickListener` instead of `Button on ClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

Check if in the class definition there is `implements OnClickListener`