# Android: onclicklistener forced close?

Tags: android, onclick

Without the onclick listener implements and its relevant codes, the activity works fine.  But when onclick listener is there it just force close.

Here is my code:

```
public class Names extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {
    private static String[] FROM = { _ID, NAME, ADDRESS, AGE };
       private static int[] TO = { R.id.rowid, R.id.name, R.id.address, R.id.age};
       private static String ORDER_BY = NAME + " DESC";


       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);

          Cursor cursor = getNames();
          showNames(cursor);

        // Set up click listeners
            View addButton = findViewById(R.id.add_button);
            addButton.setOnClickListener(this);        


       }


       private Cursor getNames() {
          // Perform a managed query.
          return managedQuery(CONTENT_URI, FROM, null, null, ORDER_BY);
       }

       private void showNames(Cursor cursor) {
          // data binding
          SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.names, cursor, FROM, TO);
          setListAdapter(adapter);
       }


      public void onClick(View v) {
         switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.add_button:
                Cursor cursor = getNames();
                showNames(cursor );
                break;                      
         }
     }
}
```

What have i done wrong?  many thanks for your help.

Comment: I think this is related to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545007/problem-with-android-button-setonclicklistener

Answer (score 0):

In these lines,
   View addButton = findViewById(R.id.add_button);
            addButton.setOnClickListener(this);

Specify which view you are using instead of using View.
e.g :- Button addButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
may be you've not cast on which View's onclicklistener you want the event